# What would happen if someone takes a sample away from a neutron star?

Tags: neutrons, neutron-stars

What would happen if someone takes a sample slowly away from a neutron star? Will it gradually change to some "normal" matter with regular atoms? If so, what atomic number will they have?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623501/mining-a-neutron-star-what-do-you-get